# High-resolution laterolog array tool

Tags: geophysics, geology, measurements

Does anybody know if it is necessary to apply corrections to the reading given by this logging tool? Corrections such as bed thickness, borehole diameter, invasion, etc.? If so, is there anywhere I can find such charts (or formulas) in order to correct the value given by the tool?

Comment: Given that a **lecture** is an educational talk given to an audience, I don't understand how you are using the word 'lecture' in your question.